# open a specific class with mouseenter on a zoomed image gallery?

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I have an image gallery where when you hover like to open a bar below the image with the download options. In inico managed to do, see the code - http://goo.gl/fhBC6

More I have a problem I do not know the solution:
How do I activate the slideDown function only in li selected?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` to select the element which the mouse is on it. 
Change Your code to this: [**jsFiddle Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/343VQ/14/)

```
$('.photos-list').on('mouseenter', 'li', function(){
    $(this).find('.openDiv').slideDown();
});
$('.openDiv').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.openDiv').slideUp();
});
```

But i think it's better to use [**hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) : **[jsFiddle Live Demo (hover)](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/343VQ/16/)**

```
$('.photos-list li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.openDiv').slideDown();                                      
},function(){
    $('.openDiv').slideUp();                     
});
```

Comment: Oh no man, I do not think that's it?????

I gave that blunder now!!

Thank you @Siamak.A.M!